# Displaying text in Code Explorer (Structure View) below / above method entries

Tags: delphi, ide, editor, delphi-xe7

I am looking for a way to to display text in the [Code Explorer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Code_Explorer) (*not* the Code Editor - I've just used the $Region as an example of something which causes text to be displayed in the Code Explorer).

Code Explorer lists procedures and functions (and more) in the same pane that is used by the Structure View when you are working in the Form Designer.

[image]

(FormActivate is the first procedure in this example | FormDeactive the last one)

I spent serveral hours looking for a way to do this but couldn't find anything. That's why i decided to ask this question here.

Does someone know a way of achieving this? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Chris, Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @bummi I am sorry. I went through so many sites / blogs and couldn't find anything. So StackOverflow was my last hope. I think i may have to live without this functionality then :(

Comment: I think the code explorer is designed to show a view of the code. So it just ain't going to show comments.

Comment: You might take a look at [Software Recommendations beta](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) but read the help there first to see if your question might fit for this site.

Comment: It's a list of methods, routines, classes, variables,... .
Procedures and functions are listed chronological like you coded them in your class. I thought it would be nice display some kind of "header text" within the Code Explorer for the sake of clarity.

Comment: @bummi: From the OP's comments on SiverWarior's answer, it seems fairly clear that he's not asking for a s/ware recommendation but an answer to something like "how do I make text appear in the structure pane below one of its items?"  The q ought to make this clearer though, if I'm understanding him aright.

Comment: @MartynA it would need a radical change of the question by Chris but might rescue the question from being closed ;-)

Comment: @Chris a good edit maybe `I went through CnWizard, GExperts, ddevextensions and some more - but without success.` should be removed, but then it would be on topic.

Comment: There is no built-in support for doing so. You might be able to write your own expert that would add this functionality, but you might end up fighting with the IDE itself - I'm not sure how much extensibility is available via Expert Interfaces (ExptIntf or whatever the current name is) to enhance the Code Explorer.

Comment: Based on documentation (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Structure_View) Structure View alows adding new nodes via right click Context Menu. Now I'm not on my development to test this out, but it might be posible to use this aproach for adding some aditional comentaries to code explorer.

Comment: @SilverWarior That sadly won't work because it adds the node at the bottom of class.

Comment: Is it perhaps posible to rearange the nodes via using drag and drop?

Comment: @SilverWarrior Code Explorer doesn't support drag and drop.